# How to get signal strength of both the sims inserted in phone

Tags: android, telephonymanager

For getting signal strength of one sim i am doing this

```
int mSignalStrength = 0;
    private final PhoneStateListener phoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
            mSignalStrength = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
            mSignalStrength = (2 * mSignalStrength) - 113; // -> dBm
            ApplicationConstants.signalStregth = mSignalStrength;
        }
    };
```

**TelephonyManager**

```
 TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting signal strength of dual sim 
i am using both TelephonyManager and SubscriptionManager

```
     fun getRegisteredCellInfo(cellInfos: MutableList<CellInfo>): ArrayList<CellInfo> {
    val registeredCellInfos = ArrayList<CellInfo>()
    if (cellInfos.isNotEmpty()) {
        for (i in cellInfos.indices) {
            if (cellInfos[i].isRegistered) {
                registeredCellInfos.add(cellInfos[i])
            }
        }
    }
    return registeredCellInfos
}


 fun getNetworkStrength(): Pair<Int, Int> {

    var strength1 = -1
    var strength2 = -1


    val manager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE) as SubscriptionManager


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        val telephonyManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager


        if (telephonyManager.allCellInfo != null) {


            val allCellinfo = telephonyManager.allCellInfo
            val activeSubscriptionInfoList = manager.activeSubscriptionInfoList

           val regCellInfo= getRegisteredCellInfo(allCellinfo)

                activeSubscriptionInfoList.forEachIndexed { Subindex, subs ->

                    if (activeSubscriptionInfoList.size >= 2) {

                        if (regCellInfo.size >= 2) {

                            if (subs.simSlotIndex == 0) {

                                if (subs.carrierName != "No service") {


                                    strength1 = when (val info1 = regCellInfo[0]) {
                                        is CellInfoLte -> info1.cellSignalStrength.dbm
                                        is CellInfoGsm -> info1.cellSignalStrength.dbm
                                        is CellInfoCdma -> info1.cellSignalStrength.dbm
                                        is CellInfoWcdma -> info1.cellSignalStrength.dbm
                                        else -> 0
                                    }

                                    Timber.i("subs $subs")

                                    Timber.i("sim1   ${subs.carrierName}  ${subs.mnc}  $strength1")
                                } else {

                                    strength1 = -1
                                }

                            } else if (subs.simSlotIndex == 1) {

                                if (subs.carrierName != "No service") {

                                    strength2 = when (val info2 = regCellInfo[1]) {
                                        is CellInfoLte -> info2.cellSignalStrength.dbm
                                        is CellInfoGsm -> info2.cellSignalStrength.dbm
                                        is CellInfoCdma -> info2.cellSignalStrength.dbm
                                        is CellInfoWcdma -> info2.cellSignalStrength.dbm
                                        else -> 0
                                    }
                                } else {

                                    strength2 = -1
                                }

                            }

                        }
                    }else if(activeSubscriptionInfoList.size == 1)
                    {

                        if(regCellInfo.size >= 1) {

                            if (subs.simSlotIndex == 0) {

                                if (subs.carrierName != "No service") {


                                    strength1 = when (val info1 = regCellInfo[0]) {
                                        is CellInfoLte -> info1.cellSignalStrength.level
                                        is CellInfoGsm -> info1.cellSignalStrength.level
                                        is CellInfoCdma -> info1.cellSignalStrength.level
                                        is CellInfoWcdma -> info1.cellSignalStrength.level
                                        else -> 0
                                    }
                                } else {

                                    strength1 = -1
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        strength2 = -2

                    }
                }

            }
        }

    Timber.i("final strenght   sim1 $strength1  sim2 $strength2")

    return Pair(strength1, strength2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check  this it will help you.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html

Comment: i have used the phonestatelistener to get signal strength of 1st sim ,but how can i get signal strength of the second sim inserted in my phone